# How do I access a StandardItemModel's data without registering the object?

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I have a nested listview structure where I am storing a map of QAbstractItemModels that contain a listview's children.  I can gather the correct model using an invokable method called "subModelFromId", but I am having trouble displaying the data from this model.

The model seems correct as the list view displays the appropriate number of items...

I do not wish to register every model in C++ using the "setContextProperty" function, but perhaps this is essential?  Is there a way to access the data in the model without registering each model?

QML:

```
ListView {
    model: items.subModelFromId(delegateID.id)
    delegate:

        ItemDelegate{
        Text {
            text: edit.name //????? Not working
       }
    }
```

C++ populating the model:

```
QAbstractItemModel * subModel = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    const int newRow= subModel->rowCount();
    const SequenceItem newSequenceItem("PM Setup","sequence", false, "pm_setup", "done");
    subModel->insertRow(newRow);
    subModel->setData(subModel->index(newRow,0),QVariant::fromValue(newSequenceItem),Qt::EditRole);

    const int newRow2= subModel->rowCount();
    const SequenceItem newSequenceItem2("Test 1","test", false, "test 1", "done");
    subModel->insertRow(newRow2);
    subModel->setData(subModel->index(newRow2,0),QVariant::fromValue(newSequenceItem2),Qt::EditRole);

    m_subModelMap.insert("PM_ID", subModel);
```

SequenceItem.h:

```
#ifndef SEQUENCE_ITEM_H
#define SEQUENCE_ITEM_H

#include <QObject>

#include "sequence_items.h"

class SequenceItem
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getName WRITE setName)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString status READ getStatus WRITE setStatus)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool checkedStatus READ getCheckedStatus WRITE setCheckedStatus)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString id READ getID WRITE setID)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString type READ getType WRITE setType)


public:
    SequenceItem();
    SequenceItem(const QString& name , const QString&  type, bool checkedStatus, const QString&  id, const QString&  status );

    QString getName() const;
    void setName(const QString &name);

    bool getCheckedStatus() const;
    void setCheckedStatus(bool checkedStatus);

    QString getID() const;
    void setID(const QString &ID);

    QString getStatus() const;
    void setStatus(const QString &status);

    QString getType() const;
    void setType(const QString &type);

private:
    QString m_name;
    bool m_checkedStatus;
    QString m_ID;
    QString m_status;
    QString m_type;
};

#endif // SEQUENCE_ITEM_H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to also create a column in the model, thus both calls to `setData` fail as indicated by their return value. All you need to  change is to add the line `subModel->insertColumn(0);` after the line `QAbstractItemModel * subModel = new QStandardItemModel(this);` in which you create the item model.